# Thread-Safe Random Array

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a way to create a Random Array/List/HashSet WITHOUT using `lock()` or the `Concurrent*` set of methods?

My goal:

- Be able to Add and Remove strings as I please (or be able to Add and "disable" strings)
- Be able to Clear the list or swap out the entire sets of strings
- Be able to get an item from it (Kind of like TryPeek) to choose ANY item RANDOMLY without using a Mixture of .ElementAt with Random of .Count/.Count()

I'm attempting to create a system to choose a Proxy at complete random from a collection that can be modified by another thread either removing or adding new proxies at any time.

Here's some "Randomizing" solutions thrown around a lot and why they are bad and shouldn't be used

#### .ElementAt(Random.Next(List.Count)) is NOT a good way to randomize a list

This is extremely unsuitable for a multi-threaded scenario for multiple reasons.
Even with a lock(){} wrapped around it and all other code to do with the collection can cause conflicts in a modified enumerable.
What I mean is, the List can change its count (perhaps lower) causing an error to be caused with .ElementAt when it chose lets say the final element, but that final element JUST got removed from the list right before ElementAt gets to it, causing an exception.

#### .OrderBy(Random)

Is also another bad way as it will randomize the entire list before choosing an element and is susceptible to Collection being modified while executing OrderBy causing an exception.

Both of the bad ways to randomly choose 1 item from a list can be "solved" by simply .ToArray()'ing before .OrderBy(Random) or before you do the .ElementAt but you also must use the ToArray()'s count for the .ElementAt's Random.
The issue here too is that this will be bad for memory depending on what your doing your essentially doubling the memory usage for the list.

This is why i'm asking if there's any kind of way to randomize efficiently without the possibility of multi-threading conflicting with modifications to collections.

#### Current Code

```
lock = new object();
...
lock (_Lock) {
    proxy = proxyArray.ElementAt(proxyArray.Count == 1 ? 0 : rand.Next(0, proxyArray.Count - 1));
}
```

I'm doing a count == 1 ? 0 so that it doesn't even bother wasting CPU randomizing for an obvious answer.

#### My attempt with ConcurrentBag

```
object proxiesRefill = new object();//for lock
...
while (!concurrentProxiesBag.TryTake(out proxy)) {//keep attempting until it takes a proxy
    lock (proxiesRefill) {//it failed possibly because its empty lets lock and check on 1 thread
        if (concurrentProxiesBag.IsEmpty) {//if its empty lets refill
            concurrentProxiesBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>(hashsetDisabledProxies);//Refill by creating a new ConcurrentBag and adding all disabled proxies to it [Properly threadsafe? not sure]
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);//sleep for 100ms just to cool down a small bit
}
//Got proxy
hashsetDisabledProxies.Add(proxy);//Disable proxy as its taken out of the active proxy bag by TryTake
//Its a hashset for no duplicates that could possibly get added.
```

Comment: If you want a lock-free solution, you can try `ImmutableList<T>` and `ImmutableHashSet<T>` - see more about the [Immutable Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt452182(v=vs.111).aspx). Then your collections will be immutable and thus thread-safe, and any changes will create a new collection that can be atomically swapped for the old one, but with lower memory usage than just copying the collections around.

Comment: Why use ElementAt() and not just the list's indexer?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel proxyArray in my currentcode is a hashset, so i use .elementat. Lots of array like objects dont have an indexer like []

Comment: Having a hash set be "randomly ordered" seems weird to me. Also, using words like "arrays" and "lists" for things that do not have random access capababilities is only going to confuse people. Use "collection" instead.

Comment: Your first option and what appears to be your current code is completely threadsafe unless you are misusing the lock by using a different object for different accesses or by accessing it outside the lock elsewhere. You would have threadsafety issues if you swapped it out for a concurrent collection because you would be in effect doing the count and the fetch with two distinct memory barriers.

Comment: @AdamG For the lock I have every lock related to this operation referenced to once that they all are in scope to use so I believe I used it correctly. At the moment im actually attempting using ConcurrentBag to my advantage as I realized using this I dont actually need to keep hold of the proxies in a second collection. I can just .TryTake from the bag and hold onto the item taken, its now disabled from other threads, when I want it undisabled I can .add it back... Why did I not think of this... My only issue now is handling for less proxies than threads running.

Comment: Does ConcurrentBag.TryTake, take from the 0 index or from anywhere in the list? MSDN doesnt specify

Comment: Have you considered shuffling the items ahead of time and putting them in a ConcurrentQueue? [Not quite the same semantics : 'random' vs 'shuffle', but maybe fairer?] Only when the queue is empty would you lock, shuffle and refill it.

Comment: Can you explain more why the proxy needs to be chosen at random? I understand why you might need to reserve a given proxy for a thread but can't see what you hope to achieve by returning a random one.

Comment: @IanMercer good idea but isnt that what concurrentbag is essentially doing in terms of the ConcurrentQueue? They seem very similar with the methods. Couldnt I do a .Count on the Bag if its 0 using lock() and refill using .Add and then .TryTake?

Comment: @AdamG Doesnt need to be "Random" just I need it in such a fashion where each thread uses as little duplicate proxies at the same time but if theres lets say 10 threads running and only 5 proxies i cant just do a take in order as theres 5 threads, by the time we start to give thread 6 a proxy, theres none left.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just use Round Robin?

Comment: One other technique for allocating n of something to m of something else in a way that's efficient as one of n or m changes slowly (e.g. adding or removing proxies) is to use consistent hashing.

Comment: How about using a concurrent queue. Take from the front, then immediately enqueue that item again if you are happy to share it with other threads or when you're finished with it. Maybe have a class with two methods borrow() and return() which hides from your consuming classes the implementation detail.

Comment: Just updated with an attempt using ConcurrentBag. Im worried my implementation of a refill isnt good.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code:

```
while (!concurrentProxiesBag.TryTake(out proxy)) {//keep attempting until it takes a proxy
    if (concurrentProxiesBag.IsEmpty) {//if its empty lets refill
            concurrentProxiesBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>(hashsetDisabledProxies);//Refill by creating a new ConcurrentBag and adding all disabled proxies to it [Properly threadsafe? not sure]
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(100);//sleep for 100ms just to cool down a small bit
```

`IsEmpty, Count, ToArray(), GetEnumerator()` lock the entire structure;